# One Hot Encoding Python Different Category

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am using Artificial Neurol Network for ML application. Columns of data are categorical. That's why I use one-hot encoding methods to all of features. Let me ask my problem. Imagine my column,

```
ANTENNA_TYPE

1234

3345

3412

5435

5623
```

I have 5 antenna type. When I one-hot-encoded, the output would be,

```
1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 1
```

After that, the next time to train and predict.

When I wanna predict different antenna type as 9999, I don't know how can I convert to one-hot encode? 
Are there any one who suggest me the best practice about it?

Thanks in advance.

```
hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
dataset = hot_encoder.fit_transform(dataset).toarray()
```

Comment: Find all the the types of classes of that column and then hot-encode it. I mean to say that hot encode the whole dataset, before splitting the dataset into test and train sets.

Comment: Yes, I did it. But what should I do If I wanna predict different antenna type? My model will be worked as API. My client send me what they want to predict? How can I handle when they send new antenna type? How can I convert it? to set 1 1 1 1 1 for all column is the best practice?

Comment: Got it! but you can do nothing if that is the case because your model's input layer will also need to be changed. What you can do is to find possible classes and fix the input layer, else consider it as continuous and don't hot encode.